# Create Basic Landing Page to allow a user to start/stop an AWS Windows EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-ec2

I would like to create a landing page using Beanstalk/EC2 (beanstalk for PHP or .NET) that is a simple HTML landing page with a Start and Stop button, allowing a non-technical person to spin start/stop a specific AWS EC2 instance (Windows Server 2012) in the same VPC.

1. Is it possible for me to start/stop the separate EC2 Windows instance from my beanstalk web app?
2. Would I need to setup anything specifically on the EC2 Windows instance to enable this to work?
3. Would I need to setup anything special on the Beanstalk instance to enable what I've described to work?

Thanks again for any pointers anyone can provide.

Answer (score 1):

1. Is it possible for me to start/stop the separate EC2 Windows instance from my beanstalk web app? **Yes**
2. Would I need to setup anything specifically on the EC2 Windows instance to enable this to work? **No**
3. Would I need to setup anything special on the Beanstalk instance to enable what I've described to work? **No**

So how do you achieve this? 
1. If you wanted a frontend GUI, you could use nodeJS. This is a good resource for that: https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-browser/
2. Your backend will have AWS CLI installed and handle all the API calls. This is a good resource for that: https://aws.amazon.com/cli/
3. You can always automate a pipeline structure using Jenkins and the many AWS plugins. So say you want to give the user parameters to select from without building anything fancy. Jenkins will do this for you with the AWS plugin and the parameter plugin.

So there are many ways to handle this. To decide which works best for you make sure you have the business requirements well defined and then maybe setup an agile like structure were you have an epic and user stories.
Hope that helped. Happy hacking!!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A further question:

Would it be feasible to create a basic ASP.NET page on a Beanstalk for .NET instance and the install AWS-CLI on this instance, and then just call AWS-CLI commands directly from the ASP.NET application?

Comment: That would be totally plausible